# Socket.io is not connecting it is not logging out the connected message on the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

I am trying to connect to socket io but is is not connecting

```html
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(express.json());

const DB = "";

io.on("connection",(socket) => {
    console.log("connected!");   
});

mongoose.connect(DB).then(() => {
    console.log("connection successful");
}).catch((err) => console.log("no connection"));    

server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

when i start the sever "connected!" is not loging on the console please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `io.on("connection", ...)` event only occurs when a socket.io client connects to your server.

It's not a startup message in the same way that your other `console.log()` statements are so you won't see it until a socket.io client connects.